# Configuring SSL certificate on Windows Apache

Tags: windows, ssl, apache-2.4

I have located two `httpd-ssl.conf` files in apache. One is in `/extra` and one is in `/original` folder. I am supposed to configure just the certificate, bundle, key paths. Should I edit on both `httpd-ssl.conf` files, or just the one in `/original`?

Why are there two such folders, `/extra` and `/original`?

Comment: We can't know _why_. If both configs refer to the same certificates, update them both. If not, don't. Maybe even check if the configs are being loaded at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to edit the one in `extra/`.

To make sure, look for an `Include` directive in the `conf/httpd.conf` file (which is the main config file of Apache). Only the files included from the main config file will be parsed, thus, you need to modify only those files.

Comment: Thanks! Haven't tried yet but I found Include directive in the main httpd.conf commented out that which points to extra/httpd-ssl, will try it!